# Integrate function in R

Tags: r

From the code:

```
integrand <- function(x) {1/((x+1)*sqrt(x))} 

a <- integrate(integrand, lower = 0, upper = Inf)
```

Then, it provides the result: 3.141593 with absolute error < 2.7e-05

How to keep only the value 3.141593?, because I need to calculate a+3 using R.

Thanks

Comment: Read the documentation of the function `integrate()`, section **Value**.

Comment: `a` is a list, and you need `a$value`

Comment: @AndrewGustar Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Although it prints as a character, you can tell by

```
str(a)
```

that `a` is in fact a list with `value` as its first element. So you can get that value easily:

```
# by name
a$value
a[['value']]

# or index
a[[1]]
```

If you are interested in why it prints as a character: `str(a)` also tells you that `a` has a `class` attribute set to `integrate`. It turns out that `print` has a method for this class: you can find `print.integrate` in `methods(print)`. This method determines the printing behavior. Normal printing can be forced by `print.default(a)`.